# can I ask for a raise even when I'm paid way above the top?

Tags: raise, performance

The fact is that I'm already being paid over the top and a raise seems very odd. The way I got to my current salary was because I was counter offered two times in a year, two years ago. I learn real quick and engineer solutions that often are implemented in less time and saves third party contracts.

By the first counter offer I was looking for a job focused in my PhD field but I stayed at the old company because I was promised they were going to open a related department... that didn't happened. By the second counter offer I was promoted to a higher technical position which required knowledge I didn't master at that time... challenge accepted.

Anyway, right now I'm into financial issues and I really need this raise, I feel I can get another job and get the money (hopefully) but I'm really loving what I'm doing right now, so...

Do you see odd/crazy/nonsense to ask for a way higher raise? Could there be a way to negotiate this?

Comment: I kind of find the two statements contradictory: "being paid way over the top" and "into financial issues". If you're paid way above average already, why are you having financial issues? Are you stuck at a small company?

Comment: Can ask for anything you want, worst that can happen is they say no.

Comment: @cst1992 Yeah, I didn't want to elaborate on that part but basically I made some bad investments and now mortgage is kind of compromised (plus family got accustomed to a level of life).

Comment: You probably want to get more certain than "hopefully" "feel" that you can get another job that pays more.

Comment: You aren't worth more to your company because you have mortgage/lifestyle issues, so why should they pay you more.

Comment: Last raise was Nov 2014. I know I need to come up with something so I asked the roadmap to become Principal... they're still defining it.

Comment: If they've countered twice, are you sure you're being paid over the top? Companies usually don't counter if the offer is way above market rate.

Comment: I've been told I earn like a manager with the last counter, which from where I am is over the top of Seniors developers salary. Probably a Principal could make a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never hurts to ask, but:

> The way I got to my current salary was because I was counter offered two times in a year

If you've already had two counter offers given to you and accepted, I'd be very surprised if they were willing to give you a raise unless it was justified.

> The fact is that I'm already being paid over the top

You recognise you're already being paid above the standard rate very handsomely, I doubt a reasonable justification could be given for a further raise.

In addition to this, you've been counter offered twice. There's a risk in asking for a raise before an annual review, they might see this as taking them for a ride and subsequently start looking for your replacement.

I'd recommend waiting until the topic is opened in an annual review of some kind.

Otherwise, look for the higher paying job and go to it. I wouldn't recommend accepting a third counter offer, if you do, expect to be out of the job within 2 years and keep that CV updated.

Comment: To be honest, some months after the second counter offer, I started to think I was about to be replaced and got paranoid, so I started to get involved in more projects and actively participated in solving the most critical issues (aside my own projects). Now, I'm the reference for complex problems though I'm more like a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

So theoretically, it **depends on how much leverage and bargaining power you have** if you decide to do this. It can go one of the following ways:

- You get the raise you ask for
- You get less than what you ask for
- You get nothing
- You get nothing + a bad reputation
- You get fired (very unlikely to me)

So if you know that you're in a top bracket, you already kind of know where you stand. But if you in a position where your company thinks that you're really really good, you might actually get another raise.

You're also going to need to **make a tradeoff based on your financial situation** because you put yourself in a situation where you either **work "for the money"** or **work "because you love what you do"**.

**Working for money** would mean that you absolutely need to search for a higher paying position, then there is no risk to ask for the raise explaining the situation. The worst case will be a 'no' and then you can move to another job with no regrets. A best case is that you get your raise and everything stays the same.

**Working because you love what you do** would mean that you're willing to downscale your lifestyle so that you can stay at the job you love. Here everything stays the same, and you don't have financial woes anymore (hopefully). It's something to consider since it is a valid solution in this scenario *(root cause = finances, take out root cause then no question)*.

Comment: Ok, so that means one out of five chances of getting the right thing plus time to actually get the raise... pretty odd.

Comment: Not all of these options are equally likely.